# Programmatically-created subfolder not visible in Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, windows-7, directory

I'm trying to add a subdirectory to an existing path.

Win-7 64, Intel SSD

Logged into company domain as a user with admin priv, but not as "Administrator"

Visual Studio 2008, launched normally (not "Run as Admin")

Here's MyApp (WinForms, Debug, x86):

```
 [STAThread]
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     string p = @"C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\MyApp";
     Directory.CreateDirectory(p);
     string f = "a.txt";
     string fullPath = Path.Combine(p, f);
     File.WriteAllText(fullPath, string.Empty);
     Directory.Delete(p);
```

As expected, the last line throws IOException: "The directory is not empty". Should mean the subdir and file got created.

Problem: Windows Explorer does not show the MyApp subdir (even after refresh, type path in address bar, close/reopen, or reboot).

C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\ was created by another application's installer; Windows Explorer says its current owner is System.

Used same IDE to create a console app (Debug, x86), copied the above lines and ran; Windows Explorer was happy to show me DigitalTestApps and the file inside.

If I do any one of the following to MyApp, the problem goes away (i.e. Windows Explorer shows me the "MyApp" subdir and the file inside):

- Build as x64
- Launch Visual Studio using "Run as Admin"
- Use any name other than "MyApp" (but I need to use MyApp for legacy reasons)

What could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe there is a folder "C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\MyApp" but it's hidden?

Comment: Make visible `System files and folders` in `folder options` then try

Comment: try typing the path of the file in the windows explorer something like this `%MyApp%`

Comment: @DJKRAZE: That will do absolutely nothing unless there happens to be an environmental variable named `MyApp`.

Comment: Check if you can find your directory & file somewhere in C:\Users\JimC\AppData ([Folder virtualization](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/folder-virtualization-concepts-windows-vista))

Comment: I am aware of that Ken but if he can't navigate to the folder because it's hidden then doing so will validate that if it exist.. also have you tried adding a `\` to the following like so 
`@"C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\MyApp"\`

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817142/why-virtualization-on-programdata-folder-in-ms-vista

Comment: Is there a new menu entry "show compatibility files" (similar to this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VistasShowCompatibilityFilesAndTheScrumptiousWonderThatIsFileVirtualization.aspx) when you browse the parent folder that should contain the new directory and file?

Comment: @dtb: Holy cannoli, there it is: C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\ProgramData\MyCompany\DigitalTestApps\ Please enter an answer for this so I can give you due credit.

Comment: @elmoVanKielmo: Hidden and system folders were already shown.

Comment: @Shaharyar: Hidden and system folders were already shown.

Comment: @DJ Kraze: no related env var, and I don't understand your 2nd suggestion, but I've got a solution now.

Comment: So, please tell us how did you managed to solve it?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: I deleted the virutalized directory from under C:\Users and it started working fine. Not sure how it got created in the first place, but seemingly, while it exists, attempts to create the directory where I was expecting it finds the virtualized one instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dtb was too humble (or busy) to repost his comment (which solved my problem) as an answer, so I'll copy his comments here to make it easier for others to see how this turned out:

"Check if you can find your directory & file somewhere in C:\Users\JimC\AppData (Folder virtualization).
related: [Why Virtualization on ProgramData folder in MS Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817142/why-virtualization-on-programdata-folder-in-ms-vista)"

So here is what I did after reading his advice:

I deleted the virutalized directory from under C:\Users and it started working fine. Not sure how it got created in the first place, but seemingly, while it exists, attempts to create the directory where I was expecting it finds the virtualized one instead.

Thanks again dtb.